# WPF ComboBox SelectedItem Binding Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have the following ComboBox that gets populat from an enum:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbProductStatus" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource statuses}}" 
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Status}" />
```

Please, note that the DataContext gets set in code-behind.

It's not even about two-way binding, I have some default value for Product.Status but it never gets selected.

**Updated**

I was asked to put code of my Status property.

```
public class Product    {
    //some other propertties
    private ProductStatus _status = ProductStatus.NotYetShipped;
    public ProductStatus Status { get { return _status; } set { value = _status; } }
}

public enum ProductStatus { NotYetShipped, Shipped };
```

Comment: Have a look at your output window when running under the debugger and see if it's telling you anything about binding to Status.

Comment: Can you give the code for your Status property? I would have expected something in the Output window if it's just not able to Bind.

Comment: You'll want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the correct event with "Status" as the value if you want to see changes show up in your GUI. As long as your ItemSource contains enums though I would have thought you'd get the default setting. There are some debugging tips for binding on my blog you might find useful. Click on my name if you're interested - there's a link there.

Comment: @Russell thanks for the debugging tip. My DataItem appears to be null. I think it's because ItemSource is set to a StaticResource, while the DataContext of a parent container is set in code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your status property must notify its change and your Product class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Here you have the MVVM Light code snippet for the property ;-)

```
/// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="MyProperty" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string MyPropertyPropertyName = "MyProperty";

        private bool _myProperty = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the MyProperty property.
        /// TODO Update documentation:
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
        /// </summary>
        public bool MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _myProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_myProperty == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var oldValue = _myProperty;
                _myProperty = value;

                // Remove one of the two calls below
                throw new NotImplementedException();

                // Update bindings, no broadcast
                RaisePropertyChanged(MyPropertyPropertyName);

                // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
                RaisePropertyChanged(MyPropertyPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

ComboBox binding is a little tricky. Make sure that the itemssource is loaded when you assign the DataContext and that the item you assign with SelectedItem meets the == relation with one item in the ItemsSource.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The ItemSource is loaded, it's just a static enum.

Comment: For non-enum-types implementing .Equals(object) on the model-class does the trick.